# Piping without creating specific pipe descriptors

Tags: c, shell, pipe, piping

I have a project to copy shell commands on C. One of the commands is | which needs to be made using piping. My other commands works but I haven't been able to make (ls | sort) work. It says that 
ls cannot access |: no such file or directory
ls cannot access sort: no such file or directory

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to fix the piping issue? It started with trying to make it so I wouldn't have to make a separate pipe for each command, so i ran it through a for loop.

The function that does most of the work is execute. Runsource and Rundest do the opening and transfer of info in pipe.

```
void execute(char *cmdline)
{
    int pid, async;
    char *args[MAX_ARGS];
    char *pargs[MAX_ARGS];
    int i = 1;
    int j;

    int nargs = get_args(cmdline, args);
    if (nargs <= 0)
        return;

    if (!strcmp(args[0], "quit") || !strcmp(args[0], "exit"))
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    int npargs = get_pipe(cmdline, pargs);
    if (npargs > 1)
    {
        int pdes[2];
        pipe(pdes);

        for (j = 0; i < npargs; j++)
        {
            nargs = get_args(pargs[j], pargs);
            runsource(pdes, j, pargs, npargs);
            rundest(pdes, j + 1, pargs, npargs);
            close(pdes[0]);
            close(pdes[1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (args[i] < args[nargs])
        {
            if (strcmp(args[i], ">"))
            {
                freopen(args[i + 1], "w", stdout);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            if (strcmp(args[i], ">>"))
            {
                freopen(args[i + 1], "a", stdout);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }

            if (strcmp(args[i], "<"))
            {
                freopen(args[i + 1], "r", stdin);
                args[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }


    /* check if async call */
    if (!strcmp(args[nargs - 1], "&"))
    {
        async = 1;
        args[--nargs] = 0;
    }
    else
        async = 0;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) /* child process */
    {
        execvp(args[0], args);
/* return only when exec fails */
        perror("exec failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) /* parent process */
    {
        if (!async)
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        else
            printf("this is an async call\n");
    }
    else /* error occurred */
    {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmdline[BUFFSIZE];

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("COP4338$ ");
        if (fgets(cmdline, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            perror("fgets failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        execute(cmdline);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any tabs in the code you copy'n'paste and then indent.  It makes a mess.

Comment: Yes, you have to know about the pipe before you process the command before or after the pipe.  You call a function `get_pipe()` but don't include that in the question. There are other missing functions too. This isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]). It is hard to know what your `get_pipe()` function does.  You need it to split `ls -l | sort -k2n -k5n | sed 's/   */ /g' | less` into 4 separate sets of command plus arguments, and the pipe won't appear in any of the argument lists. The `sed` command needs just two arguments, too, and no quotes (shells remove them). You can skip quoted argument stuff pro tem.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have special code to handle the "<" and ">" symbols, but I don't see any code in your answer that handles "|", so how were you even expecting it to work?  The problem now is that you are passing "|" as an argument to `ls`, when in fact you should be running the thing after the pipe as a command sending the standard output of `ls` to that command's standard input.

Why are you trying to invent a shell from scratch by parsing stuff and setting up pipes manually?  Can't you just use [`system()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to execute a shell command instead?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to know the "|" was there before you ran ls because then it would run and send to standard out when instead i would want to send it to the next command

Comment: Also one of the main points of the assignments was to integrate piping into it. I'm just having trouble making code that can pipe when it has to rather than manually coding the pipes

Comment: No, the whole point of the `system()` call is that it executes the command with your shell (`/bin/sh` according to the documentation I linked to in my answer).  Your shell will parse the pipe character and do the appropriate thing, because that's one of the main things that shells are supposed to do.  If this is homework, did the teacher explicitly say you cannot use `system()` or run an external shell like sh or bash?